# Windows XP not detecting IDE drive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, pata

I'm trying to install another hard drive into an old Dell I use as a server machine.

I unplugged the main HDD with the OS, and plugged the secondary HDD into that IDE port, because it had Linux on it and I wanted to boot from that. I know the HDD started because I can hear it moving, but the BIOS won't detect the HDD.

If I plug it into another IDE port while Windows is running, Windows shudders to a halt and hangs.

What's going on, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Ide is not plug and play. You could be or have damaged the drive. I killed a 40GB drive that way.

Comment: @CarlB What do you mean, not plug and play? How can I tell if the drive is damaged? I've tried two, hope I didn't kill them both...

Comment: I think he may mean "Hot swappable".  That means you can't just pull the drive while the machine is running.

Comment: @JasonH Ok, I see. Hope I didn't do any damage. Too used to working with SATA.

Comment: @JasonH - exactly, poor word choice on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On IDE drives you may need to set the jumper on the drive to "Master" if it's the drive you want to boot with.  If it isn't and you want it as a secondary set the jumper as slave.

http://www.easeus.com/resource/images/install-ide-hard-drive-jumper.gif[image]

Comment: I did a bit of "repining", and managed to get it to pop up as "Primary Master Drive" and "Primary Slave Drive", It seems to boot off the master fine, but I get "error: out of disk" when trying to boot from the slave drive.

EDIT: Seems like it's causing boot errors again. Windows XP is taking a LOT longer to load, and I'm predicting a blue screen coming on...

Comment: YOu can only have one drive in master mode and all other drives (4 or less) in slave mode.  Clarify something for me here.  YOu have 2 drives, one windows, one linux.  Which OS do you want to run?

or are you replacing the windows hdd all together?

Comment: I want to boot linux as the main os, and keep the windows drive as a backup operating system, just if I don't like linux. After I get it installed, I'll probably switch the drives around, or just set the boot priority to the slave.

Comment: Okay well make sure that whatever IDE cable you are connecting your master drive to that if there is another device that it is also in slave mode.  Meaning if you have a cdrom drive on the same IDE cable that it is in slave mode.  I would shy away from unhooking your XP drive and then plugging it in as a slave to your linux drive unless you don't care about your XP load.  If you're going to swap back and forth just make sure you shut things down before you do it.

Comment: XP also does not like it when the disk order changes. Keep XP as the first drive (e.g. first IDE channel, master) and the Linux drive as second drive (first IDE channel, slave). If that changes drive 'letters' then you need to adjust this in /etc/fstab. Mostly likely by by replacing /dev/hdaX with hdbX.  If you have third IDE device, try setting both to 'single' and on their own IDE channel.